C++ ThreadPool Hangs with Multiple Threads but Works with a Single Thread
I am attempting to divvy up work between multiple threads using a thread pool, where each thread can then pass data through stdout to a child program (in this case cat to verify operation of it.
The program hangs (leaving all of it's child programs running) whenever I specify the number of threads as above 1, but always exits as expected when the number of threads is equal to 1.
A minimal reproducible example of the issue is below:
#include <atomic>
#include <csignal>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

atomic<bool> running(true);
mutex coutMutex;

void handle_signal(int signal) {
    if (signal == SIGINT) {
        running = false;
    }
}

class ThreadPool {
    vector<thread> threads;
    queue<function<void()>> taskQueue;
    mutex queueMutex;
    condition_variable cv;
    atomic<bool> stop;

public:
    ThreadPool(size_t threadCount) : stop(false) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i) {
            threads.emplace_back([this] {
                while (true) {
                    function<void()> task;
                    {
                        unique_lock<mutex> lock(queueMutex);
                        cv.wait(lock, [this] { return stop || !taskQueue.empty(); });
                        if (stop && taskQueue.empty()) return;
                        task = std::move(taskQueue.front());
                        taskQueue.pop();
                    }
                    task();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    ~ThreadPool() {
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(queueMutex);
            stop = true;
        }
        cv.notify_all();
        for (thread& t : threads) {
            t.join();
        }
    }

    void enqueueTask(function<void()> task) {
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(queueMutex);
            taskQueue.push(std::move(task));
        }
        cv.notify_one();
    }
};

void workerFunction(size_t start, size_t end, const vector<const char*>& args) {
    int pipefd[2];

    if (pipe(pipefd) < 0) {
        perror("pipe");
        return;
    }

    // Set the write end of the pipe to non-blocking
    int flags = fcntl(pipefd[1], F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(pipefd[1], F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        return;
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        // In the child process
        close(pipefd[1]);  // Close unused write end
        dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(pipefd[0]);

        execvp("cat", const_cast<char* const*>(args.data()));
        perror("execvp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        // In the parent process
        close(pipefd[0]);  // Close unused read end

        string data = "Example data ";
        
        for (size_t i = start; i < end && running; ++i) {
            size_t written = 0;
            while (written < data.size() && running) {
                ssize_t bytes = write(pipefd[1], data.c_str() + written, data.size() - written);
                if (bytes == -1) {
                    perror("write");
                    break;  // Exit the loop on error
                }
                written += bytes;
            }
        }
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(coutMutex);
            cout << "Reached end!" << endl;
        }
        
        close(pipefd[1]); // Ensure write end is closed
        int status;
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(coutMutex);
            cout << "Worker finished. Exit code: " << WEXITSTATUS(status) << endl;
        } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(coutMutex);
            cerr << "Worker terminated by signal: " << WTERMSIG(status) << endl;
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    signal(SIGINT, handle_signal); // Handle exiting early gracefully for the child processes

    vector<const char*> args = {"cat", nullptr};

    size_t totalCombinations = 100;  // Example number
    size_t threadCount = 1; // exits fine with 1 thread, hangs >1
    ThreadPool threadPool(threadCount);

    size_t chunkSize = totalCombinations / threadCount;
    size_t remainder = totalCombinations % threadCount;

    size_t start = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i) {
        size_t end = start + chunkSize + (i < remainder ? 1 : 0); // Chunk up our tasks
        threadPool.enqueueTask([=, &args]() {
            workerFunction(start, end, args);
        });
        start = end;
    }

    return 0;
}

It should be compiled by the most recent version of g++.

This makes no sense. Why are you using fork with std::thread? Why are you guarding atomics with locks? I should also add this is not very minimal.

The issue seems to come from workerFunction (and not by the ThreadPool class itself) and the process management (frozen on waitpid). It is strange by the way to create processes (ie. call to fork) with a class supposed to manage threads.

My apologies for it not being a very well laid out method as I am not the most experienced with C++. What would be a more appropriate way to do this? Is there a specific term or methodology that I can search for that I am not aware of?

Consider using osyncstream instead of locking cout with a mutex, your threading code runs fine so the problem is likely with waitpid

You have a race-condition, if two threads fork at the same time then the 3 processes will have the 4 ends of the 2 pipes open, you likely need to add a mutex around it, then set the file descriptors to not be inheritable by exec anymore, another alternative is to specify the exact file descriptors to be inherited while calling posix_spawn (which you must use if you have more threads in the same application)
#include <atomic>
#include <csignal>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

atomic<bool> running(true);
mutex coutMutex;

mutex fork_mutex;

void handle_signal(int signal) {
    if (signal == SIGINT) {
        running = false;
    }
}

class ThreadPool {
    vector<thread> threads;
    queue<function<void()>> taskQueue;
    mutex queueMutex;
    condition_variable cv;
    atomic<bool> stop;

public:
    ThreadPool(size_t threadCount) : stop(false) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i) {
            threads.emplace_back([this] {
                while (true) {
                    function<void()> task;
                    {
                        unique_lock<mutex> lock(queueMutex);
                        cv.wait(lock, [this] { return stop || !taskQueue.empty(); });
                        if (stop && taskQueue.empty()) return;
                        task = std::move(taskQueue.front());
                        taskQueue.pop();
                    }
                    task();
                }
                });
        }
    }

    ~ThreadPool() {
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(queueMutex);
            stop = true;
        }
        cv.notify_all();
        for (thread& t : threads) {
            t.join();
        }
    }

    void enqueueTask(function<void()> task) {
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(queueMutex);
            taskQueue.push(std::move(task));
        }
        cv.notify_one();
    }
};

void workerFunction(size_t start, size_t end, const vector<const char*>& args) {

    int pipefd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    {
        std::lock_guard l(fork_mutex);
        if (pipe(pipefd) < 0) {
            perror("pipe");
            return;
        }

        // Set the write end of the pipe to non-blocking
        int flags = fcntl(pipefd[1], F_GETFL, 0);
        fcntl(pipefd[1], F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
        // set fds as non-inheritable across exec
        fcntl(pipefd[0], F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
        fcntl(pipefd[1], F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);

        pid = fork();
    }
    
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        return;
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        // In the child process
        close(pipefd[1]);  // Close unused write end
        dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(pipefd[0]);

        execvp("cat", const_cast<char* const*>(args.data()));
        perror("execvp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        // In the parent process
        close(pipefd[0]);  // Close unused read end

        string data = "Example data ";

        for (size_t i = start; i < end && running; ++i) {
            size_t written = 0;
            while (written < data.size() && running) {
                ssize_t bytes = write(pipefd[1], data.c_str() + written, data.size() - written);
                if (bytes == -1) {
                    perror("write");
                    break;  // Exit the loop on error
                }
                written += bytes;
            }
        }
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(coutMutex);
            cout << "Reached end!" << endl;
        }

        close(pipefd[1]); // Ensure write end is closed
        int status;
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(coutMutex);
            cout << "Worker finished. Exit code: " << WEXITSTATUS(status) << endl;
        }
        else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(coutMutex);
            cerr << "Worker terminated by signal: " << WTERMSIG(status) << endl;
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    signal(SIGINT, handle_signal); // Handle exiting early gracefully for the child processes

    vector<const char*> args = { "cat", nullptr };

    size_t totalCombinations = 100;  // Example number
    size_t threadCount = 10;
    ThreadPool threadPool(threadCount);

    size_t chunkSize = totalCombinations / threadCount;
    size_t remainder = totalCombinations % threadCount;

    size_t start = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i) {
        size_t end = start + chunkSize + (i < remainder ? 1 : 0); // Chunk up our tasks
        threadPool.enqueueTask([=, &args]() {
            workerFunction(start, end, args);
            });
        start = end;
    }

    return 0;
}

In my opinion, fork + exec should be replaced by posix_spawn, another alternative is to move fork to the main thread then you spawn a thread to do only the stdin writing and the  waitpid, so you don't need the mutex, you are not getting a speed boost anyway because fork needs to be done under a mutex.
